# Should tags include the definite article?

Tags: discussion, tags

Following on from keithjgrant's comment here.

Assuming that tags will be in French (which I believe they should), should they include the definite article? I.e. *grammaire* or *la grammaire*?

(I say *grammaire*, what say you?)

Comment: `la-grammaire` sounds as weird as `the-grammar` would. Why on earth would one even consider `la-grammaire`?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say *grammaire*, without any hesitation. *la grammaire* just sounds wrong to my internal grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Same here, I don't see the point in having extraneous characters in tags which don't have any added value. I'd pick *"grammaire"* over *"la grammaire"* any time.

Same way I would also pick *"traduction"* over *"traduction-en-fr"* as, as discussed elsewhere it's the only one we'll deal with anyway.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of what is a *word*, there's no reason a **key***word* should be **two** words.

It is not a “keynoun”, and therefore there's no question whether nouns should get an article or not: it is a keyword, and words do not need articles. On the contrary, if you add an article, it's not one word anymore.

Definition: Word: “the smallest free form that may be uttered in isolation with semantic or pragmatic content” ([Wikipedia EN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word))

In the French Wikipedia: “suite de signes […] pouvant être distingués par un séparateur (**blanc typographique à l'écrit**, pause à l'oral)” - [Wikipédia FR](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot). The Académie Française's dictionary is not as specific with the separator, but its definition does not conflict with Wikipedia's.

Ok, I think that's enough formal justification for what everyone agreed on by gut feeling  ;)